# jqgrid using local data only displays one row

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I'm having trouble with a search results page. The search page has 16 inputs and the results page uses a dynamic query to fetch the results and input them into an array which is used (with json_encode) to populate a jqgrid with the results. However, the grid is only displaying the first record. I've added a php "echo 
json_encode()..." script to the page to view the json formatted results and it's showing all the records in the search results, so I don't know why the grid is only displaying the first row. I'd appreciate any help I can get on this. Here is the script for the grid (I'm not including the dynamic query or the array scripts because they're working fine):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#slist").jqGrid({
data: "srchres",
datatype: "local",
mtype: "GET",
colNames: ['ProjectID', 'Customer Name', 'Invoice Number', 'Vehicle Info.', 'Project Date'],
colModel: [
{name:'ProjectID', index:'ProjectID', align:'right', hidden:true, editable:false},
{name:'CustomerName', index:'CustomerName', editable:false, width:175, align:'center'},
{name:'InvoiceNumber', index:'InvoiceNumber', editable:false, width:175, align:'center'},
{name:'VehicleInfo', index:'VehicleInfo', width:350, align:'left', editable:false},
{name:'ProjectDate', index:'ProjectDate', editable:false, width:125, align:'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'm/d/Y' }},
],
jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "ProjectID"},
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
var rowData = $(this).getRowData(rowid);
document.location.href = "../manageproject.php?pid=" + rowData['ProjectID'];
},
pager: "#spager",
loadonce: true,
rowNum: 20,
rowList: [],
width: "auto",
height: "auto",
caption: "",
sortname: "",
sortorder: "",
viewrecords: true,
gridview: true
});
var srchres = <?php echo json_encode($projects_array); ?>;
for(var i=0;i<srchres.length;i++)
jQuery("#slist").addRowData(srchres[i].id,srchres[i]);
});
```

Comment: Ok, so I got the grid to display all the rows by changing the datatype from local to json. But now the pager isn't working properly. I have rowNum set to 20 but it's displaying all the records on the first page and the page numbers says it's on page 1 of 0.

Comment: This is becouse you use addRowData - this method does not take the pager into account and is used mostly for internal purposes. I recommend you not to use the addRoeData, but to change your code something like this: see the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following settings into the grid:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var srchres = <?php echo json_encode($projects_array); ?>;
    $("#slist").jqGrid({
        data: srchres,
        datatype: "local",
        ....
    });
...
```

});

Note the variable **srchres**  and how is defined into the grid options. addRowData is not needed to be used.

Comment: Thank you Tony, but when I use your suggestion, the grid isn't populating at all.

Comment: Can you please post some data? - i.e can you please tell us how look **$projects_array**